# how can create function select all column in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, stored-functions

How can create an function (Stored Procedure / Stored Function) that select all column in the table in PgAdmin? That same same like this.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GetAllUsers(IN userno integer)
  RETURNS TABLE(all column) AS
$BODY$
BEGIN 

    RETURN QUERY    
        SELECT  *
        FROM Users W 
        WHERE w.UserNo = GetAllUsers.userno;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100
  ROWS 1000;
ALTER FUNCTION GetAllUsers(integer)
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `returns setof users` instead of `returns table (...)`

You also don't need an expensive PL/pgSQL function for that. A plain SQL function is enough:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getallusers(p_userno integer)
  RETURNS setof users
$BODY$
   SELECT *
   FROM users 
   WHERE userno = p_userno;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE
  COST 100
  ROWS 1000;
```